# SQLite - Select ranks of distinct combinations of columns

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite db that looks as follows:

```
id | num1 | num2 | value 
---|------|------|------
1  |  2   |  1   | "foo"
2  |  1   |  1   | "foo"
3  |  2   |  4   | "foo"
4  |  2   |  3   | "foo"
5  |  1   |  1   | "foo"
6  |  1   |  1   | "foo"
7  |  1   |  3   | "foo"
8  |  1   |  2   | "foo"
```

I need to select the following:

- all columns
- the number of distinct combinations of `num1` and `num2`
- the `num1`/`num2` combinations' rank ordered by `num1` and then `num2`

The resulting table is supposed to look like this:

```
id | num1 | num2 | value | num | rank
---|------|------|-------|-----|-----
1  |  2   |  1   | "foo" |  6  |   4  
2  |  1   |  1   | "foo" |  6  |   1  
3  |  2   |  4   | "foo" |  6  |   6  
4  |  2   |  3   | "foo" |  6  |   5  
5  |  1   |  1   | "foo" |  6  |   1  
6  |  1   |  1   | "foo" |  6  |   1  
7  |  1   |  3   | "foo" |  6  |   3  
8  |  1   |  2   | "foo" |  6  |   2
```

I tried fiddeling around with lots of different subqueries but didn't get anything close to a useful result.

---

EDIT: I managed to get the number of combinations (so column `num`) using the following query:

```
SELECT
*,
(
SELECT count (*)
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT num1, num2
FROM table)
)
AS num
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank can be computed by counting the distinct rows that are equal to or smaller than the current row.
A row is smaller if `num1` is smaller, or if `num1` is equal and `num2` is smaller.

```
...,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM (SELECT DISTINCT num1, num2
       FROM MyTable) AS T2
 WHERE T2.num1 < MyTable.num1
    OR (T2.num1  = MyTable.num1 AND
        T2.num2 <= MyTable.num2)
) AS num,
...
```